# Integral Inequality ( Possibly makes use of Fubini's theorem )

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Prove that integrals on R^n satisfy :

$\int_{B(0,1)} 1/|x|^a dx < \infty  $  iff  $  a<n $

$\int_{B(0,1)^c} 1/|x|^a dx < \infty $ iff $ a>n $

I think that this might be porved with the help of fubini's theorem , but I have no clue on how to apply that here , or if applied on how to prove this with it.

( I know that this can be solved by the polar co-ordinates , I am looking for another way ) 
I am not so sure but I think that some time ago I have seen a pretty similiar version of this question on this site , if you know about it link me to that question .

Comment: By the general "polar coordinates" transformation on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\int_{B(0,1)} |x|^{-a}\,dx = \sigma(S^{n-1}) \int_0^1 \rho^{-a} \cdot \rho^{n-1}\,d\rho$ where $\sigma$ is the measure on the unit sphere.

Comment: I am looking for a way to solve this which doesn't require polar coordinates .

Comment: Could you give a reference as to what you meant by Fubini's inequality?

Comment: @Chee han I have corrected my mistake , I meant fubini's theorem basically .